# Array gives last element as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I am trying to write a function that deletes items from an array and you can undo the deletion by the undo function. If you pass an argument into the undo function starting with 0 as the first item and you pass 2 ( as 3 items) it returns undefined for the last item and I dont know why does it happen.
I tried tweaking the undo function and sometimes it returnd empty place in array and even empty x2.

Can someone please explain why does that happen?

```
let testLista = ['Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Sun'];
let testUndo = [];
let i = 0;

const delItem = del => {
    let indexOfDel = testLista.indexOf(del);
    if(testLista.includes(del)){
        testLista.splice(indexOfDel, 1);
        document.write(`<h3>Deleted: <em>${del}</em></h3>`)
        testUndo[i] = del;
        console.log('delItem() undo - ',testUndo);
        console.log('delItem() list - ',testLista);
        i++;
    }else{
       document.write(`<h2>That item does not exist! Available items: <em>${testLista.join(', ')}</em></h2>`);
    }
}

delItem('Sun');
delItem('Saturn');
delItem('Mars');
 
const undoFunc = (undo) => {

    if(undo >= 1 && undo < testUndo.length){
        for(let j = 0; j <= undo; j++){
            testLista[testLista.length] = testUndo[j];
            testUndo.splice(j, 1);
            console.log('Undo() - ', testUndo);
        }
    }else{
        testLista[testLista.length] = testUndo[testUndo.length-1];
        console.log('Undo() - ', testLista)
    }

};
```

Here is my html:

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an SSCCE that contains your HTML as well.

Comment: HTML contains only default doctype declaration and script tag for this js file i included.

Comment: So how would your user undo something?

Comment: Its just a practice code. I call the undo function in browser console.

Comment: OK then, let me amend my original request: please create an SSCCE that contains HTML.

Comment: HTML in javascript or my HTML code?

Comment: You're using `.splice()` in a loop without taking into account the fact that the length of the array has been shortened.

Comment: @slappy testLista still gives me undefined, splice simply deletes items.

Comment: I know it does. I'm telling you why.

Comment: If you want the loop to repeat `undo` times, then you need to use `j < undo` instead of `j <= undo`.

Comment: @Ivar That returns only 3 items not four and it still gives me undefined.

Comment: I don't think you're seeing the issue. If `undo === 3` and `testUndo.length === 3`, then no problem, right? But what will `testUndo.length` show after the first iteration? You removed something from the array, so now `testUndo.length === 2`, but you're still iterating up to `3`. And after the second iteration, `testUndo.length === 1`, but again, you're iterating up to `3`. Does that help?

Comment: Your question should include the call(s) to the `undo` function, and show what the expected result is, and what you get instead. It would also be nice if you would explain what the `undo` argument means that is passed to the `undo` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to `testUndo.splice(j, 1);` in your `undo` function.

The **splice()** method adds/removes items to/from an array at given index, and returns the removed item(s).

***Note**: This method changes the original array.*

You are iterating over `j` and upto `j<2`;

```
for j=0 | testUndo = ["Sun", "Saturn", "Mars"]
```

spice will delete item at index **0** i.e `testUndo = ["Saturn", "Mars"]`

```
`for j=1 | testUndo = ["Saturn", "Mars"]`
```

spice will delete item at index **1** i.e `testUndo = ["Saturn"]`

`for j=2 | testUndo = ["Saturn"]`
now there is no item at the index at 2, hence it will not delete anything.

Solution - you should splice at array at index 0

```
for(let j = 0; j <= undo; j++){
            testLista[testLista.length] = testUndo[0];
            testUndo.splice(0, 1);
            console.log('Undo() - ', testUndo);
        }
```

Comment: Your solution won't fix it. The same problem exists.

Comment: Thanks, solved it. I didnt realise that I was deleting items im trying to add.

Comment: Also explanation is good but the example wont fix it. Splice deletes items and every next item is put on first place so the fix was testLista[testLista.length] = testUndo[0];

Comment: @DarioK Yes, I have missed to update testLista. Now updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `splice` inside a loop can often lead to undesired results: as you reduce the size of the array by it, but increase the loop variable, you have two problems:

1. You'll skip elements: `splice` moves values to the left, in order to fill the gap of the deleted value. But you still increase `j` in the next iteration, so one value slips through the mazes...
2. As the array gets shorter and shorter, eventually `j` will point to an index that *would* have existed if you hadn't shortened the array, but now that it is shorter, it points beyond the end of the array, hence the `undefined` value.

The solution is to not use `splice` within the loop, but only once *after* the loop, where it can remove all the iterated values in one go:

```
        for(let j = 0; j <= undo; j++){
            testLista[testLista.length] = testUndo[j];
            console.log('Undo() - ', testUndo);
        }
        testUndo.splice(0, undo+1);
```

I should note that it is a bit unconventional to define `undo` as the last index to remove. It would make more sense to define `undo` as the *count* of items to remove.

Also, why not use `testLista.push`?

Then you would have:

```
        for(let j = 0; j < undo; j++) { // now `undo` is a count!
            testLista.push(testUndo[j]);
            console.log('Undo() - ', testUndo);
        }
        testUndo.splice(0, undo); // no more `+1`
```

And using spread syntax, you can even get rid of the loop (still using the more logical definition of `undo`):

```
        testLista.push(...testUndo.splice(0, undo));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```js
let planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Sun'];
let deletedPlanets = [];
const planetList = document.getElementById('planet-list');
const deletePlanet = (planet) => {
  const ind = planets.indexOf(planet);
  deletedPlanets.push({ind, planet});
  planets.splice(ind, 1);
  drawPlanetList();
};
const drawPlanetList = () => {
    planetList.innerHTML = '';
    planets.forEach((planet) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = planet;
    div.onclick = () => {
        deletePlanet(planet);
    };
    planetList.appendChild(div);
  });
}
const deleteMultiple = () => {
    deletePlanet('Mars');
  deletePlanet('Jupiter');
  deletePlanet('Sun');
  
    drawPlanetList();
}
const undo = () => {
    if (!deletedPlanets.length) {
    return ;
  }
  const undoObj = deletedPlanets.pop();
  planets.splice(undoObj.ind, 0, undoObj.planet);
    drawPlanetList();
}
drawPlanetList();
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0.4em;
  border-bottom: 1px inset gray;
}
```

```html
Clicking on list elements deletes them.
<button onclick="deleteMultiple()">
 delete multiple
</button>
<button onclick="undo()">
 undo
</button>
<section id="planet-list"></section>
```